# Invert vs reverse

Tags: word-choice

Say I rewrite "A → B" as "A ← B".

Do we say that I've **inverted** or **reversed** (or **reverted**) the arrow? (Or maybe some other word is most suitable.)

Comment: Did you consult a dictionary for these three word?

Comment: Say rather that you wrote something meaningful…

Is it clear that rewriting "A → B" as "A ← B" does not explain whatever you're asking?